# Show images depending of time?

Tags: php

As a little experiment, I wanted to see if it was possible to make a little time-based ad service.

This will be the way it'll work:

- The user uploads an ad banner
- The service will allocate **display time** instead of clicks. Everyone gets an equal part of the allocated 24 hours.

And here's my problem...

My brain does not compute it. At all.

If there are two ad banners, I want the first one to be displayed from 0:00 to 12:00 and the last one from 12:01 to 23:59.

That's easy to program using simple if statements. Sadly, the number of banners can change, so I must make some kind of dynamic statement-thing. I know it has probably something to do with `foreach()` but again I'm unsure of what I should use.

I'm not asking for a complete solution.

I want to know if something similar already has been done, and most of all, what docs should I look at to achieve my goals.

As of now, here's my code:

```
$num = count(glob("/var/www/html/ad/a/" . "*"));
$dist = 24 / $num; // Outputs number of files in the ads folder
```

Cheers.

Comment: Let me see if I understand the problem. Given a number of banners x and a 24-hour time period, you want to write a function that will evenly allocate an equal amount of display time for each banner in that period? IS that correct?

Comment: Yes! Exactly! Im completely lost on what I should do here..

Comment: Well the first step is simple arithmetic. 24 hrs=1440 minutes, so 1440/x is how many minutes each banner will get in a day

Comment: Then, I would maybe set each banners time period off of that, for instance, banner 1 would get from 00:00-00:10, banner 2 from 00:10-00:20 and so forth.

Comment: Do some research on the time() and date() functions, try writing some code yourself, then if you are still having issues, post your code and we can help you.

Comment: The problem is that the ad numbers keeps changing! I just dont know how I could make my time alocation function..

Comment: Ill do some research on that. Thanks!!

Comment: What I would do is create a database entry of some kind with 'BannerID' 'StartTime' and 'EndTime', then write a function that will run each day to calculate these values.